# Sample last N days per group data using PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying sample last 180 days of data per serial number from 10 years worth of data. My approach was working fine for the following toy data. But it doesn't give me the desired data for the real dataset that I am working with. Here is the toy example:

I wanted to get last 2 days of data per serial number from here:

[image]

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark3.2show').getOrCreate()
print('Spark info :')
spark
url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/8c6a6effa98a8fe5cd86dc59d5959a87/raw/8c192ab825ad8191517bc9c2425a723df745cc2d/RecentNBeforeFailure.csv"
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
df=spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("RecentNBeforeFailure.csv"), header=True,sep='\t')
```

The following code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df.withColumn(
    'date', F.to_timestamp(F.col('date'), 'M/D/yyyy')
).withColumn("r", F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy("serial_number") \
                           .orderBy(F.col("date").desc()))) \
    .filter("r <=2") \
    .drop("r") \
    .show()
```

gives

[image]

which seems correct for this toy example. In a real dataset I have 10 years worth of data and I wanted to sample last 180 days of data using the following code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
OldSpark180=OldSpark.withColumn(
    'date', F.to_timestamp(F.col('date'), 'M/D/yyyy')
).withColumn("r", F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy("serial_number") \
                           .orderBy(F.col("date").desc()))) \
    .filter("r <=180") \
    .drop("r")
```

Not sure why it returns me whole 10 years of data instead of giving me last 180 days per serial number data.

In Pandas it seems pretty easy:

```
pandas_df.sort_values('date').groupby('serial_number').tail(2)
```

Comment: it looks okay to me, but hard to see the problem when we don't have the actual data, and as you say, you don't have a problem with the toy dataset.  Can you try to replace the `.filter("r<=180").drop("r")` with `.groupby("r").agg(F.max(F.col('r')))` and confirm that your data is returning `r` values >180?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Output on your sample dataset (with 2 days filter):

[image: Output_new]

---

This would work:

```
df.withColumn('date', F.to_timestamp(F.col('date'), 'M/D/yyyy'))\
.withColumn("max_date", F.max("date").over(Window.partitionBy("serial_number")))\
.filter(F.col("date")> F.col("max_date") - F.expr("INTERVAL 180 days"))\
.drop("max_date")\
.show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Also, to understand problem with your code - consider if there are only two dates one 10 years back and one today, in that case there would be only two ranks 1 and 2 which would then be retained as per your filter. See below dataframe prior to filter in that case:

[image: Output_old]

As you can see the row with the year 2010 is ranked 3, thus won't be filtered out.

Comment: .filter(F.col("date")> F.col("max_date") - F.expr("INTERVAL 2 days")) doesn't return anything for this toy dataset. I wanted to get last 2 days from this toy dataset.

Comment: @ForestGump can you add code to prepare the toy dataset?

Comment: url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/8c6a6effa98a8fe5cd86dc59d5959a87/raw/8c192ab825ad8191517bc9c2425a723df745cc2d/RecentNBeforeFailure.csv"

Comment: @ForestGump Updated answer, check now. It was due to date format - `F.to_timestamp(F.col('date'), 'M/D/yyyy')`